# XML 1.1 number version is not valid with xml document

Tags: xml, vb.net, version, xmldocument

I have a xml document like this

```
    <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <p:FatturaElettronica versione="1.1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
            <DatiTrasmissione>
                <IdTrasmittente>
                    <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
...
```

If i use:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(filePath)
```

I receive an error:

> 1.1 is not a valid version

Why, how can i do for read xml with this version?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to remove `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` and tested??

Comment: I think version must be 1.1.0

Comment: i can't change the document

Comment: Are you validating this xml with any xsd??

Comment: The error message seems quite descriptive. After a quick look at a random sample of XML files I have in my computer, I have confirmed that all of them have version="1.0". Also according to the associated MSDN article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048.aspx), 1.0 is the current version. You should either make sure that the input information is right or reduce the strictness of your parsing approach. That is: change the corresponding options in the XML reader; or read it as a plain text file; or do a mixed approach: read it as text file to memory, modify it and use XML reader.

Comment: Looks like 1.1 isn't widely supported, this may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231675/does-net-4-5-support-xml-1-1-yet-for-characters-invalid-in-xml-1-0

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It assumes that not having the first line has no consequences.

```
    Dim fileLines As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList
    fileLines.RemoveAt(0)
    Dim fileAsString As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, fileLines)

    Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Parse(fileAsString)

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(xe.CreateReader)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you download an example of file FatturaPA from http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/it/a-3.htm you will notice that xml version is 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica versione="1.1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So maybe your file is not correct.