# processing XML version 1.1

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file which is in version 1.1. Upon googling I understood the .Net doesn't support XML version 1.1.

I am trying to load a stream using XDocument as below

```
 var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

It throws error.

Is there any other way to handle this version of XML ?

I also try to look at XmlPrime. Does XmlPrime support version 1.1

- Alan -

Comment: Unless the XML is actually using 1.1 specific feature, it would be much easier to process the XML as 1.0. Related question : [Does .Net 4.5 support XML 1.1 yet (for characters invalid in XML 1.0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231675/does-net-4-5-support-xml-1-1-yet-for-characters-invalid-in-xml-1-0)

Comment: You can read it as text and then change 1.1 to 1.0.