# How can I change the version of the xml document that is in the header?

Tags: c#

how can I change the version that has the xml header?.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the XML version?

Comment: This is equivalent to ask "how to change the version from 1.0 to 1.1", because there are only those two XML versions, hence I will propose a duplicate for that below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does .Net 4.5 support XML 1.1 yet (for characters invalid in XML 1.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231675/does-net-4-5-support-xml-1-1-yet-for-characters-invalid-in-xml-1-0)

Comment: Are you aware that this is not a document version, but the XML version?