dotnetRDF AllegroGraphConnector XML error when querying
Code

AllegroGraphConnector connector = new AllegroGraphConnector(
    "https://someid.allegrograph.cloud/",
    "root",
    "mystore");

string sparqlQuery = @"ASK { ?s ?p ?o }";

var result = connector.Query(sparqlQuery); // This lines throws error


The problem

When using any well-formed query, I get the following error:

Version number '1.1' is invalid. Line 1, position 16.

Full error (as image):


What have I tried?


Using the dotNetRdf.Client & dotNetRdf.Core packages instead of the full dotNetRdf NuGet package
Try different queries (malformed ones throw different error (MALFORMED), good ones all throw the one above.
Give my anonymous user sudo rights
Try AllegroGraphServer which did connect properly and didn't give errors (can't query with this instance though)
Look for answers in the docs/source code
Looked for similar answers on internet: first, second

Querying the store on the AllegroGraph web view does work (the above SPARQL query should simply return 'true'.
I suspect the problem is any of the following:

Some compatibility/version issue (.NET, NuGet, dotnetRDF, XML)
dotnetRDF bug (seems unlikely though as my usage is VERY basic)
Misconfiguration of server (I just made a new repository on the root catalog)
Human error

Software


LINQPad 8 (.NET 8.0.3)
Visual Studio 2022 (.NET 8.0)
dotNetRdf

Update

When doing the same SPARQL query with only HttpClient using ?query I get the following result:
<?xml version="1.1"?>
<!-- Generated by AllegroGraph 8.2.1 -->
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head/>
  <boolean>true</boolean>
</sparql>

The error therefore relates to the XML version 1.1 returned by the AllegroGraph server. It seems AllegroGraphConnector doesn't support parsing XML 1.1.
Finally

Thank you in advance for answering/commenting. Any help is welcome.
Please keep in mind that I am new to the Semantics Web world and thus new to AllegroGraph, dotnetRDF, SPARQL, etc.

I think issue is with HTTP version.  Version 1.0 is stream mode.  Version 1.1 is chunk mode.  Looks like Allegro want version 2.0.  See remarks at bottom of follow page : https://dotnetrdf.org/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Storage_AllegroGraphConnector.htm  The link for 2.0 is broken on the link I provided.

From what I can see HTTP version 1.1 should be used.  2.0 is version of Sesame.  Documentation is here : https://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/http-protocol.html.  I think issue is with the ASK.

@jdweng so basically the AllegroGraphConnector class is not up to date to AllegroGraph's requirements?

@jdweng please see my update in the question. I opened an issue on the GitHub to investigate this further

Why do you need XML 1.1?  I've never had to use 1.1.  Mainly needed for unicode characters.  But you can still use 1.0 and have unicode.

The issue is that the dotNetRDF parser for XML SPARQL results relies on the .NET System.Xml XML parser which does not handle XML 1.1 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231675/does-net-4-5-support-xml-1-1-yet-for-characters-invalid-in-xml-1-0).
It doesn't seem likely that .NET will be updated to support XML 1.1 any time soon. I wonder if there might be a way to configure Allegrograph to return XML results using XML 1.0 instead?
